# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Tags: angular, nebular

I am trying to open nebular dialog by ngrx effect. It works, but not the first time.

First time appears error:

> "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null"

If refresh page and the open dialog it opens

**action.ts:**

```
export const loadModal = createAction('[Products] Load Replenish Invoice Modal', props<{ payload: string }>());
```

**effect.ts**

```
loadModal$ = createEffect(
    () =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ProductsActions.loadModal),
        tap(action => {
          console.log(action);
          this.dialogService.open(ProductConfirmModalComponent, {});
        }),
      ),
    { dispatch: false },
  );
```

Here is my component where I am dispatching action:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.sub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.store.dispatch(loadCurrencies({ payload: params.type }));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like the problem refers to `<nb-layout>`, could you please provide a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/akveo/nebular-seed) exmaple?